# css - machine specific font-family

Tags: css, font-family

I'm writing a sample web-app for myself to be run on my computer.  I'd like to use a font that exists on my machine "Helvetica Neue UltraLight".  However I can't get the browser to use the font.  It can use the "Helvetica Neue" but not the Ultralight flavour.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to work: font-family:"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight".  I found it by chance.  So if I find a font I like in font-book how do I refer to it in css?

Comment: Follow Pheenix's answer. That will answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to determine the name of the specific typeface in your computer and use it. Alternatively, you can use `@font-face` with the specific font file name, provided that you use a font format recognized by the browser being used.

If the name of the typeface cannot be easily guessed, you may need to take the long route of analyzing the font using e.g. [DTL OTMaster Light](http://www.fontmaster.nl/). By CSS specifications, the name to be used is the PostScript name or the full name of the font. These can be found in the names table at entries corresponding to nameID values 6 and 4.

Or you can take a different route and use a font listing tool like http://hasseg.org/stuff/fontList/example.html or http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your operating system, you have to install the font at your operating system and check its name in-which it installed in the system, i.e not only the font's file name.

As a more global and platform independent solution you may able to use a web font and then implement it using your CSS. The following website will help you:

http://www.font2web.com/

Answer (score 1):

from within your CSS file (or wherever you are defining your styles) you have to refer to that custom font in the following manner:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: cool_font;
    src: url('cool_font.ttf');
}
```

After that you can use it just like a normal CSS declaration:

```
p.custom_font{
    font-family: cool_font; /* no .ttf */
}
```

This way you can use as many custom fonts as you feel like on your website.

Comment: Good response. Nice use of CSS3