# font-family of a font, what is it?

Tags: css, font-family

I'm trying to find the CSS `font-family` name of the Helvetica Neue LT Std 97 Black Condensed font located here:  http://fontscore.com/fonts/Helvetica-Neue-LT-Std-97-Black-Condensed_22554.html

I'm using `@font-face` to load the font onto the webpage, if not already on the users computer, however, I would like to be able to load the font, if found on the users computer first.  I've tried several methods here, but none of these work:

```
font-family:  HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Cn
font-family:  HelveticaNeueLT Std ExtBlk Cn
```

What is the name of this font that I should use when calling font-family?  I probably have to put 97 somewhere in there also, but nothing works, have tried a ton of different ways to call it.

Here's what I'm using in the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: hnc_font;
    src: local('HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Cn'), local('HelveticaNeueLTStd-BlkCn'), url('../fonts/hnc.otf') format('opentype'), url('../fonts/hnc.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/hnc.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/hnc.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face{ 
    font-family: MyFont_IE;
    src: url('../fonts/swiss_bc.eot'); 
}

.big_text
{
    padding-top: .4em;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Cn, HelveticaNeueLTStd-BlkCn, hnc_font, MyFont_IE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try all your combinations by wrapping the name of the font in `"` quotes.

For example `font-family: "Helvetica Neue LT Std 97 Black Condensed"`

Then, the name that you call is defined by your `@font-face` declaration before the `font-family`. You can call it what ever you want.

For example if you first declare it like this

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "MY_FONT_NAME";
    src: url('PATH_TO/FONT_FILENAME.ttf');
}
```

you can later refer to it like this

```
font-family: "MY_FONT_NAME";
```

**Edit** based on the added CSS

try this

```
    .big_text
{
    padding-top: .4em;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Cn", "HelveticaNeueLTStd-BlkCn", "hnc_font", "MyFont_IE";
}
```

Comment: Just now added the CSS that I'm using for this, maybe it can help, but it doesn't work if the font is already on the users computer... it always loads the font using `@font-face`

Comment: what about adding the " quotes as the code i added to my post?

Comment: Hold on, will try... will let you know

Comment: In any case their are tons of different styles for this font.  I need to load up the `97` style, only `97`, nothing else.

Comment: What exactly are you doing different?  I have tried the quotes, doesn't help, it still skips everything and goes to loading up the `hnc_font` ALWAYS.  I have the font installed on my computer, but it never loads the font from my computer, instead it loads it with the `hnc_font` why?  The only thing I can think of is that I'm not using the correct `font-family` name for the font.  But I can't find the correct `font-family` name, need help with that.

Comment: The different is that i am adding the " quotes. If you do not add them to space separated font names then they will not be loaded.
In order to find the name of the font installed on your pc, if you are using windows go to C://Windows/Fonts folder and find the exact name from there.

Comment: The name of the font is telling me this:  `HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Cn`, but a friend of mine has a MAC OSX installed computer, and has that font installed, with tons of variations and styles, and says that a different style gets loaded for that font, instead of the `97` style.  He says that it's not as bold for him, like it's a lighter font style.

Comment: Maybe it's a different name on MACs?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to mark this as solved, as I'm thinking that, since I didn't have quotes around the font names, it was loading:  `HelveticaNeueLT` instead of the whole name:  `HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Cn`, so thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: Since by CSS specifications, quotation marks are not required, and there is no evidence of browsers being non-conforming in such issues, it remains a mystery why the quotes are said to be the solution here.

Comment: Actually, I just did a w3c validation on the css file, and w3c told me that quotes are necessary, in order to be loaded by the system, when fonts have white-space in their name(s).  So, I guess I learned something new today.  In any case, Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Cheat with some javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/ucd2L/

```
var x = $("#test").css('font-family');
$("#test").append(x);
```

HTML

```
<p id="test">Text</p>
```

Comment: Don't necessarily add this to your page, just make a quick page to find out exactly what it is called.

Comment: Interesting approach, will try this now.

Comment: Awww, this is no good, returns `hnc_font` which just means that it is loading up the font using `@font-face`, but I need to get the `font-family` name of the font as if `@font-face` wasn't even being used!  So this doesn't help me :(

Comment: Thanks, this actually did work once I changed the font of my browser to said font.

Answer (score 0):

When using `@font-face`, there are two separate questions about font names.

The name you use in `font-family` declaration inside an `@font-face` rule is up to you, as long as it is a syntactically valid font name and you use that very same name in `font-family` declarations in normal CSS rules. So it can be `font-family: foobar`.

The name you use in the `local(...)` constructor when setting `src` in an `@font-family` rule must match the name under which the font is known in the system. It should be name you would use to get a local font in a `font-family` rule without any `@font-face`, and in principle it should be the PostScript name or the full name of the font, though browsers may accept other names too; see
[css - machine specific font-family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025845/css-machine-specific-font-family).